# How to get list of Datastage job using teradata connector

Tags: unix

I am using dsjob -lstageinfo

It is giving stages information but i need specific using teradata connector

Dsjob -lstageinfo
Was expecting info for teradata connector but i am getting jobs using all stages

Please help me getting only connector info either teradata or oracle